# How does the HoloLens recognize the space ? Is there any limit to the number of spaces that a HoloLens can remember?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

Does anyone know how the Hololens recongnizes the environment that it has been to? When we work with spatial mapping I find that the first time we scan the environment it spends some time mapping it. But from the second time onwards it recognizes the space and immediately puts the map associated to it.

Furthermore, I know that the HoloLens stocks data of the environment associated to the wifi. Is there any limit to the number of spaces that it can store?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any limit to the number of spaces that it can store?

The limit depends on your hard drive budget. The HoloLens will constantly read/write volumes to disk to ensure the volumes near the device are loaded to disk so that hologram occlusion works well. And only delete a space if we've hit our disk budget for volume storage.

> Does anyone know how the Hololens recongnizes the environment that it has been to?

HoloLens will search the map data connected with the current space in the spatial database to determine whether the device is in a new space. If we lose tracking and the device thinks it's in a new space, we will start a new mesh and merge that data back into our map if we later find that they are connected.

Comment: `The limit depends on your hard drive budget.` 

Is there any known limit for the file size of one map or we can infinitely map a space?

`HoloLens will search the map data connected with the current space in the spatial database to determine whether the device is in a new space. If we lose tracking and the device thinks it's in a new space, we will start a new mesh and merge that data back into our map if we later find that they are connected.`

Is there a way to force the HoloLens to load/recognize a space by giving it an Id for example?

Comment: No, there is nothing for both. Actually, you don’t need to take care on how to manage the maps. The process of HoloLens map physical spaces is a black box and we do best to make it complete these tasks intelligently without additional intervention from customers.