# Spatial Mesh Size Limit on HoloLens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, spatial, hololens, mrtk

Is there a limit to the size of the mesh the HoloLens 2's spatial observer can create? I want to be able to scan multiple rooms, roughly 120m2, and as such I have tried two different methods:

- Simply walking around and scanning the rooms, then downloading the mesh via 3D View and insert into Unity. Only a portion of the rooms I visited were scanned, resulting in an incomplete final mesh.
- Scene Understanding demo: I walked around the same rooms, saved the mesh to the HoloLens, and opened them in Unity. The resulting .obj files were also incomplete, roughly the same amount as from the Device Portal's 3D View.

Can anyone offer some pointers on how to capture larger areas? Apparently it is programmatically possible, because Huebner, et. al in *Evaluation of the Microsoft HoloLens for the Mapping of Indoor Building Environments* scanned an entire apartment using SpaceCatcher, an app apparently only compatible with the HoloLens 1.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a limit to the size of the mesh the HoloLens 2's spatial observer can create?

Does this answer your question? [How does the HoloLens recognize the space ? Is there any limit to the number of spaces that a HoloLens can remember?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684816/how-does-the-hololens-recognize-the-space-is-there-any-limit-to-the-number-of).

> Only a portion of the rooms I visited were scanned, resulting in an incomplete final mesh.

It seems like you walk too quickly around the area, which causes that the HoloLens will miss mapping areas. Please walk slowly around the space, stopping every 5-8 feet to look around at your surroundings. More information about how to build a great spatial map please see [Mapping your space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-spaces#mapping-your-space)

Comment: That partly helps; in the other post you mention that the size limit of a single map is unknown. I will update my answer when I have found an average size limit. At one point my HoloLens just stops adding new parts of the room to the mesh- you can look around all day in that area but nothing happens.

Comment: If you still cannot map the new space, it is recommended you open a support ticket through this link: http://aka.ms/hololenssupport so that we can diagnose it deeper for you.

Answer (score 1):

If a portion is not connected with the others, Hololens glass may understand that the portion is a room. So you should walk slowly around the room, make the air tap to scan, you will see the cool effect when the spatial mesh is rendering. So you can know what area is recognized by Hololens.

120m2 is not too large, I have scanned multi rooms on the same floor and it works. But I had no success trying to scan and joint rooms on 2 floors.